# Measure object dimensions in Meshlab?

Tags: meshlab

Is this simple operation even possible. I googled but couldnt find any method that gets the aligned bounding box dims of the object

Answer (score 1):

Render -> Show box corners will display the coordinates of the bounding box and its dimensions, in the top-left of the MeshLab window.
If you need to have the coordinates in text format, you can use the filter "compute geometric measures" that will print in the log lot of infos of the mesh, including also the bounding box min and max.